# Reachout to google about Arc Welder

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

Google has released ARC Welder and in the [Chrome App page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn) links to Stack Overflow:

> For questions about ARC Welder or ARC's capabilities, join us on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-arc?sort=newest

Some people are using SO and the [google-chrome-arc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-arc) as a support forum.

Comment: Okay...what's your point?  If there are off topic questions, close them as off topic.

Comment: "Reach Out" isn't code for "Somebody write [company] and tell them they're doing it wrong."  Make your request more specific: Is there a bare link to Stack Overflow saying "Get support here"?  Are there an unusual number of bad questions being posted under the tag?

Comment: I think this came up because of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433535/cannot-install-arc-welder-from-chrome-web-store-in-chrome-40-linux), or more precisely, the asker's comment `The page of Arc Welder itself on Chrome Web Store pointed here for Discussions and Issues.`  So I think it would be a good idea to make sure the support asked here for Arc Welder stays on-topic.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, there is a bare link. In the official docs: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc and in the ARC Welder app description. Yes, there has been many questions of the form "I used ARC Welder with [insert 3rd-party app here] and [feature] is not working, halp" - ignoring the fact that ARC welder is supposed to be used by developers and some features require secret API keys of the original Android app.

Comment: There's only 58 questions in that tag.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it's grown since I put this in. It was around 10

Comment: We'll get more new questions than that on Stack Overflow by the time I finish writing this sentence.