# Remove [arc] as synonym of [automatic-ref-counting] (now ambiguous)

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process

Google recently introduced ARC (App Runtime for Chrome) and actually [points to SO as its primary support channel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289287/reachout-to-google-about-arc-welder).

While links that are on Google pages link directly to [google-chrome-arc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-arc), there is a tag [arc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arc) and it's a synonym of [automatic-ref-counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automatic-ref-counting).

I think that synonym is now ambiguous and needs to be removed. I've seen at least one question in the wild mis-tagged because of this.

I **do not claim** it needs to be re-pointed to [google-chrome-arc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-arc). It's ambiguous and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Personally, I would have assumed that "arc" would be used for graphics questions, [especially SVG ones](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands).