# Reach out to Google Assistant SDK team

Tags: support, outsourcing

[This page](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/support) could do with being more specific about the type of questions that are likely to be welcomed on Stack Overflow.

At the time of writing the "Support" page contains links to

- Stack Overflow - Ask a question under the google-assistant-sdk tag.
- Google+ Community - Join the conversation on Google+

With no guidance about which to choose

[image]

(I just noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48029606/73226) that sparked this).

Comment: Google is a repeated offender: [custom surveys](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327707/reach-out-to-google-regarding-consumer-surveys), [ArcWelder](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289287/reachout-to-google-about-arc-welder) and [YouTube](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345938/google-are-sending-youtube-tech-support-upload-quota-queries-to-stack-overflow). Possibly more.

Comment: block visitors referred by that page. and they'll learn